# Bootstrap Grid adjustment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please see below screenshots. When viewing in a browser, I would like to stack these two buttons on right corner. When I shrink browser,  I still want them next by each other but they are stacking on top of each other.

[image]
[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
             <H1 class="title">New Business</H1></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><H5 class="title" > Test Name </H5></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LogOut
        </button>
     </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LogOut
      </button>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To have both buttons be in one column and at the right of the screen:

You need to replace the contents of your row with this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 btn-lg-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LogOut
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LogOut
    </button>
</div>
```

You also need to add this CSS:

```
.btn-lg-container {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Your code puts each button into it's own column. One of the columns takes up the full width of the screen on small devices, putting each button on its own line on smaller screens. My code creates only one column, which contains both of the buttons. The CSS then aligns the two buttons to the right of the screen.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/59K2N/3

### To have each button be in it's own column and at the left of the column:

On your first button, you need to change `col-xs-12` to `col-xs-6`, otherwise the first button will always take up the full width when the screen is extra-small.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/59K2N/

Comment: Thanks Joshua, But even fiddle, it shows two sepearte buttons. Is theranway we can right justified both?

Comment: @user2088016 So you're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/59K2N/3/?

Comment: I know you have changed line col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 to col-xs-12 btn-lg-container. If you don't mind, ca nyou explain me the diffrence between my code and your code? I am just trying to learn bootstrap and I am very poor in CSS. Thank you!